# Different symbol for quotation marks

Tags: javascript, html, symbols

Can't seem to find any resources for this since any attempt at searching for this gets me questions about single vs double quotes, but let me lay this out, it is not about single vs double quotes:

This is about different symbols being used for double quotes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

vs

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
```

Typically when I write code, I get

```
"
```

but some how one of my files was using

```
”
```

It was a real pain trying to troubleshoot the error;

So why are there 2 different symbols used for double quotes?

How did it come about (is there a keyboard input that gets the latter quote symbol)?

And why does only the former work in HTML code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are more than two ways to represent quotation marks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs

This usually happens when someone uses a word processor or other non-programming text editor to write code.  These programs will often substitute fancy quotation marks for their plain counterparts, causing havoc and the sacrificial slaying of kittens.

Why does HTML expect plain double-quotes?  Because section 3.2.4 of [this RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt) says so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links, how painfully annoying it is that the symbols look so close to each other yet function completely differently. I use SublimeText and it would be a good feature for them to add syntax highlighting for dummy symbols like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you paste code in Microsoft Word (for example) it tends to replace the old boring quotes `"` with the nicer looking `”`. Unfortunately this is an entirely different character and does not hold any meaning for the HTML markup.

While the code may very well have been formatted like this in some other editor, my bet is it was inadvertently converted. I've had similar problems with code before.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I choose the other answer because he provided some documentation that answered another question, but you got a +1 from me